# Bootstrap navbar and containers exceed/overflow the max-width assigned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm attempting to create a page using bootstrap 3, where I want the max-width of the page to be 800px so that there will be white space on screens which are large enough. To do this, I wrap all the pages content in a main `<div>`

My issue is that when assigning the max-width of 800px to the main div encapsulating the content of the page, the navbar and other containers on the page seem to ignore this max-width and overflow.

When experimenting with the code I noticed that when increasing the max-width to 1200px, the behaviour which is desired is achieved - however, I want to try accomplish this for 800px, not 1200px.

**Below is my HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
  <head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <!-- Navigation bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="mynavbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsemenu" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">My Nav</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsemenu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#" id="item1">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="item2">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="item3">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="item4">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="item5">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="item6">Item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="item7">Item 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="item8">Item 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="item9">Item 9</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="col1" class="col-md-6">
          <h1>Content Header 1</h1>
          <p id="infoContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>  
        <div id="col2" class="col-md-6">
          <h1>Content Header 2</h1>          
          <h4>Sub Header 1</h4>
          <h4>Sub Header 2</h4>          
        </div>      
      </div>      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**And the accompanying CSS3 code:**

```
#mainContainer {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

#col1 {
  background-color: #add8e6;
}

#col2 {
  background-color: #7997A1;
}

/* Allowing the navbar to collapse, at a screen width of 5000px or less */
@media (max-width: 5000px) {
  .navbar-header {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }
}
```

The reasoning behind the media query in the CSS file was so that the navbar would always be in a collapsed state (assuming no screen above 5000px was used).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want the 800px width for white space? putting a container around everything already has a width of 1140px. What is the purpose of the 800 px width for just the nav?

Comment: @Nick0989 The purpose of it being 800px is purely down to the desired design. The 800px was not just for the navbar, but for all the other components on the page, such as the bootstrap containers outwith the navbar also; I included them in my example to demonstrate that this issue was not exclusive to the navbar itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because bootstrap container has it's on width. 
[image]

You better change `container` `width` in `bootstrap.min.css` instead of adding your `div` with `800px`.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

You can change this to your value `800px`.

**Or** Add `max-width: 100%;` to all your `child` tag.

Comment: Thank you for the clear illustration and detail in your response! I've tried out both and are working well, I've found the first method you proposed to be the more beneficial option when thinking of ease of scaling the page. Wasn't aware that the default container attributes could be overridden like this, brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it seems that you just want to change the width of the container to 800px instead of the default container of 1140px for large screens. You don't need the "mainContainer" at all for this.

Go here...https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#container-sizes

This is where you can adjust the container class size and any other elements you want to adjust in bootstrap. You can press ctrl F to search for "container" and ctrl G to find it on the page quickly.

Enter any changes you want and then download at the bottom of the page. You'll have to read about implementing it onto your site.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nick, I've looked into what you've put forward and have learned a lot about the customisation of bootstrap now, although this method works I prefer the approach Anzil suggested allowing for the container to be customised within the CSS itself.